# Getting a dictionary key error while run a caffe model with python codes

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, caffe

I've trained a caffe model via nvidia's digits. Now I'm trying to initialize my model with a python program. I've tried some samples but I'm stuck on a dictionary key error, which tells me there is no 'prob' key. I'm new to running a deep model.
I modified "dersmon"s prediction.py codes on github:
https://gist.github.com/dersmon/8b701a41a3a1d6b45098

I've found some solutions, which I gave the links for below. The error seems to be same but it didn't work for me.
https://groups.google.com/g/caffe-users/c/gv90MUHshrM?pli=1

Here's my code;

```
import caffe
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

caffe_root = "/home/kenan/caffe/"

MODEL_FILE = caffe_root + 'models/tez_test/deploy.prototxt'
PRETRAINED = caffe_root + 'models/tez_test/snapshot_iter_13749140.caffemodel'

net = caffe.Net(MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED, caffe.TEST)
caffe.set_mode_cpu()

blob = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.BlobProto()
data = open(caffe_root + 'models/tez_test/mean.binaryproto' , 'rb' ).read()
blob.ParseFromString(data)

meanArray = np.array( caffe.io.blobproto_to_array(blob) ).transpose(3,2,1,0)
meanArray = meanArray[:,:,:,0]

img = caffe.io.load_image(caffe_root + '/models/tez_test/sample_img/res.jpg')
img = caffe.io.resize(img, (224, 224))
meanArray = caffe.io.resize(meanArray,(224,224))
img = img - meanArray
img = img.astype(np.uint8)

imageData = np.asarray([img.transpose(2, 1, 0)])
imageData = np.divide(imageData, 255.0)


out = net.forward(data=imageData)

print(format(out['prob'][0].argmax()))

imagenet_labels_filename = caffe_root + 'models/tez_test/labels.txt'

labels = np.loadtxt(imagenet_labels_filename, str, delimiter='\s')
top_k = net.blobs['prob'].data[0].flatten().argsort()[-1: -6: -1]
print (out['prob'][0])
print (top_k)
print (labels[top_k])
```

...and here's my error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deep-test.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(format(out['prob'][0].argmax()))
KeyError: 'prob'
```

I appreciate all your help.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with caffe to help, but you can start by checking the dictionary's values using `out.items()`. I don't know what the expected data for `out` is, but since you do, you may be able to get a better understanding of your problem using that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not familiar enough with caffe to help, but you can start by checking the dictionary's values using out.items(). I don't know what the expected data for out is, but since you do, you may be able to get a better understanding of your problem using that knowledge.

Thanks to Octavel
after i used out.items() i saw my dictionary key was 'softmax'. i changed all 'prob' with 'softmax' and problem solved.

Comment: Glad to have helped! Remember to mark it as the accepted answer to close the thread